# How to lookup table2 using a field in table1 and retrieve a column data from table2?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of objects like below in varialble SI's. I am trying to lookup another table `ods.tblSoftwareImages` using `SoftwareImageId` and get a list of all `SoftwareImage` from the table `ods.tblSoftwareImages`. Can anyone provide guidance on how to do that?

```
SIs
[
  {
    "ProductLineID": 17646,
    "SoftwareImageId": 17646,
    "SoftwareProductId": "2032882"
  },
  {
    "ProductLineID": 17646,
    "SoftwareImageId": 17646,
    "SoftwareProductId": "2032881"
  },
  {
    "ProductLineID": 17645,
    "SoftwareImageId": 17645,
    "SoftwareProductId": "2032883"
  }
]

public IEnumerable<SoftwareImage> GetSIForSP(int SoftwareProductID)
{
    var SIs = _entities.tblSoftwareProductSoftwareImages
        .Where(x =>x.SoftwareProductId == SoftwareProductID).ToList();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Returning `null` probably isn't going to get you what you want. Are you asking for an SQL query that will return the `SoftwareImage` (apparently a field in the `ods.tblSoftwareImages` table) for every `SoftwareImageId`?

Comment: Jim - your understanding is right,thats exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Does it need to be in an array? You could create a class and put it in a list.

Comment: the input is an array of objects and we need to return the list of SoftwareImages

Comment: Well you can convert your array into a list of objects and take your current database objects and do a join on both lists and get your data?

Comment: SIs is already a list of objects,isn't?do you have a specific example on what you mean?appreciate your help

Comment: Jim,can you help?

Comment: Pieter - can you provide guidance?

Comment: What about your code does not work yet as expected? Why are you returning `null` in `GetSIForSP` instead of `SIs`?

Comment: Flying FOX - return null was just a space holder,I need some guidance how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select imageIds from your SIs and query in images table on these Ids.
Just sample code: i don't know exactly what is the name of your table and how  Id property looks like.

```
public IEnumerable<SoftwareImage> GetSIForSP(int SoftwareProductID)
{
    var imageIds = _entities.tblSoftwareProductSoftwareImages
        .Where(x =>x.SoftwareProductId == SoftwareProductID)
        .Select(x=>x.SoftwareImageId)
        .ToList();
    var images = _entities.tblSoftwareImages
                            .Where(x=>imageIds.Contains(x.SoftwareImageId));
    return images;
}
```